# Dynamically populate template from two lists

Tags: django, django-templates, python-2.x

I want to dynamically populate a template from two lists, that contain variable values.

Could someone tell me, how could I achieve something like this:

```
current_task_resources_types = ["image", "html"]
current_task_resources_names = ["elephant.png", "index.html"]

"task": [
    {% for index in current_task_resources.length %}
        {"type": "{{ current_task_resources_types.index }}", "url": "{{ current_task_resources_names.index }}"},
    {% endfor %}
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lists in your view,

```
current_task_resources = zip(current_task_resources_types, current_task_resources_names)
```

then loop through the zipped list in your template

```
"task": [
    {% for type, name in current_task_resources %}
        {"type": "{{ type }}", "url": "{{ names }}"},
    {% endfor %}
]
```

In Python 2, `itertools.izip` may improve performance if the lists are long.